# IPhone Development - Main Thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

I am new to iPhone development and I would like to ask a question concerning asynchronous events.

Supposing I have a `NSURLConnection` and the correspoding delegate methods ie. `didReceiveResponse`, `didFailWithError` etc. The methods are called asynchronously when events are fired. Are all methods executed on the main thread? Or does the iOS create separate threads that execute the corresponding method code?

I am facing some random crashes to my app, and I guess that it is a synchronization issue.

Answer (score 2):

The delegate methods of NSURLConnection are executed in the main thread. That is the whole reason behind being asynchronous, no need to have a separate thread.

About the internals, I/O is an inherently asynchronous world, so I also do not think that internally NSURLConnection uses threading. I suppose that it is the OS that manages the communication in a async way, but I am not sure about it.

Anyway, you can be sure that your delegate methods are executed from within the main thread.